# Express-Validator "validationResult" returns [object Object]

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-validator

I'm modifying the Error handling of the Express-Validator middleware to go through my custom Error Handling middleware but the message of the `validationResult` resolves to `[object Object]`.

**Express-Validator error handling**

```
const expressValidationError = (req, res, next) => {
  const errors = validationResult(req);

  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    const err = new Error(errors.array());
    err.status = 400;
    next(err);
  } else {
    next();
  }
};
```

**Express Error Handling middleware**

```
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  const status = err.status || 500;
  res.status(status).json({
    error: {
      status: status,
      message: err.message || "Internal Server Error",
    },
  });
});
```

**This is the result of the `error` object which is returned from `validationResult`:**

```
Result {
  formatter: [Function: formatter],
  errors: [
    {
      value: 'b',
      msg: 'Username Must be Between 5 to 255 Characters Long!',
      param: 'username',
      location: 'body'
    }
  ]
}
```

**And this is the `errors.array()`:**

```
[
  {
    value: 'b',
    msg: 'Username Must be Between 5 to 255 Characters Long!',
    param: 'username',
    location: 'body'
  }
]
```

I know that I can just use `res.status(400).json({ error: errors.array() });` in the Express-Validator and avoid all these but I would prefer if it was passed to `next()` and handled by the error middleware.

**Is there any way to do so or should I just go with the other way?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is not the validator, but that the `Error` object takes a string parameter as the first parameter, and you're passing it an object (array), hence the `object object`.

so JSON.stringify the object:

```
const err = new Error(JSON.stringify(errors.array()));
```

Comment: That causes the error message to become something like this: [{\"value\":\"b\",\"msg\":\"Username Must be Between 5 to 255 Characters Long!\",\"param\":\"username\",\"location\":\"body\"}]

Comment: @Nima exactly, now you can process the error by serializing it: `JSON.parse('[{\"value\":\"b\",\"msg\":\"Username Must be Between 5 to 255 Characters Long!\",\"param\":\"username\",\"location\":\"body\"}]')` and for example display .msg value to the user

Comment: @Nima or loop the array if there are more errors

Comment: Upon further testing, I realized that I couldn't pass the parsed JSON to next() since it messes up my error middleware and shows 500 error code for every error, even if it's specified something else like 400 or 404.

Comment: @Nima try parsing it in the error middleware, there you construct the error output for the client however you wish, you could also include multiple messages, it's only important to stringify the errors when constructing `Error` to avoid `object object`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and hints! I finally managed to fix it by defining the parsed JSON outside of the `Error` class and passing that to the `Error` class:
`const parseError = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(errors.array()))[0].msg;`
`const error = new Error(parseError);`
/////////////
Now `parseError` will only show the first and most specific error message.

Comment: @Nima no, in that case you're using a string, so you don't need to serialize anything, simply pass the string value: `const parseError = errors.array()[0].msg;`. But like I said, it's up to you, what you want to show, and then how you'll pass it and process it on the client/consumer

Answer (score 2):

If you see the below code, this is what is happening. You are passing an array of objects.

```
let status = new Error([{}]);
console.log(status); // Error: [object Object]
```

Now, when you check the validation object it is something like this:

```
// errors will be like
[{ myLocation: 'body' }, { myLocation: 'query' }...]
```

All you have to make it a string:

```
const expressValidationError = (req, res, next) => {
  const errors = validationResult(req);

  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {

    // below is only useful when you don't have array of objects
    // const err = new Error(errors.array().toString());

    const err = new Error(errors.array().map(el => el['msg']).toString());
    err.status = 400;
    next(err);
  } else {
    next();
  }
};
```

Adding which key has what validation error:

```
const expressValidationError = (req, res, next) => {
  const errors = validationResult(req);

  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {

    // below is only useful when you don't have array of objects
    // const err = new Error(errors.array().toString());

    const err = new Error(errors.array().map(el => `${el[param]} - has Error: ${el['msg']}`).toString());
    err.status = 400;
    next(err);
  } else {
    next();
  }
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the outcome is still the same. Error: [object Object]

Comment: can you add the o/p of your validation in the question? That is `errors` and `errors.array()`, it will be helpful for the answer.

Comment: The Question is updated now

Comment: Check now this will add the message in the errors to the error object you create.

Comment: Now it works! Thanks a lot! Could you please explain how the "msg" value is being mapped here? I'm wondering if I can improve it a bit since now if there are two violations the outcome will be a mixture of those two violation messages with a comma seperating them. Like so: "message": "Name Cannot be Empty!,Username Must be Between 5 to 255 Characters Long!"

Comment: Yes, `Error` class accepts the string messages by default when you have multiple message make them the string and map it. Let me add that code too.